# Identify anchor tag clicked to reach server side script

Tags: php, mysql

```
while ($r1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>
    <a name='".$r1["case_id"]."'
       id='".$r1["case_id"]."'
       href='modify.php'>".
    $r1["case_id"].
    "</a></td>
    // code continues...
}
```

Multiple anchor tags will be created at run time and unique `name` and `id` will be assigned to each of them.
I want to know `id` or `name` of the anchor which was clicked to run `modify.php`.

Comment: Include the `id` as `GET` parameter in the `href` and read it from your script.

Comment: Pass an ID as GET Parameter. Like `href='modify.php?id=".$r1["case_id"]."'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this -

```
<td><a name='".$r1["case_id"]."' id='".$r1["case_id"]."' href='modify.php?id=".$r1["case_id"]."'>".$r1["case_id"]."</a></td>
```

And when `clicked` get that with php

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
   echo $_GET['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a name="<?php echo $r1['case_id'];?>" id="<?php echo $r1['case_id']?>" href='modify.php?id=<?php echo $r1["case_id"]?>'><?php echo $r1['case_id']?></a></td>
```

send id using query string and get the is in php page using `GET method`

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
   echo $_GET['id'];
}?>
```